# Monitoring a Apache Karaf/OSGi application via SNMP

Tags: osgi, monitoring, snmp, apache-karaf

We are building OSGi (particularly using Apache Karaf on Equinox) applications that need to be delivered into customer environments that commonly employ SNMP based monitoring tools. Can anyone suggest a cost effective (Open source is ideal, but has to use a license that we can ship as part of our commercial offering) framework/package that will support SNMP? Bonus points for avoiding SNMP API bleeding into the applications bundles we deploy (I'd rather have our developers define JMX MBeans instead). Our customers may dictate the monitoring system we need to plug into for deployment, but we use Nagios for internal testing, so further points for nagios-friendly solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Currently on Github there is an effort to create a webconsole extension for the karaf webconsole that will actively monitor Karaf MBeans and display them in a manner similar to JVisualVM.  As of now, that effort has largely been halted due to the rewrite of the karaf webconsole to use Pax-Wicket.  That effort is largely completed, so the jmx-webconsole will be rebooted and rewritten in pax-wicket.  As committer on that effort, I am going to add the ability to publish jmx mbean information via snmp.  Please let me know exactly what you'd expect to see as part of this.  If we can provide SNMP support outside of the jmx-webconsole, I'd also consider that.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the monitor specification on OSGi, so all the bundle expose their monitorable object and you need to implement a bundle that expose the monitorable object as snmp or whatever protocol you need.
This links references at the API https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v41/org/osgi/service/monitor/package-summary.html